# Multiple IF statements in Django/Python

Tags: python, django

I was wondering if someone could help me out here, I'm struggling to group my IF statements together in such a way to achieve my results.  I'm pretty new to python/django so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to make a 'Like' and a 'Dislike' button for my webpage.  I have it all set up and I can have each individual element working but I can't seem to group them.  What I'm trying to say is this, this will allow me to 'like' my post:

```
class PostLike(View):

    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
        else:
            post.likes.add(request.user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('image_details', args=[slug]))
```

This will allow me to 'dislike' my post:

```
class PostDislike(View):

    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        if post.dislikes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.dislikes.remove(request.user)
        else:
            post.dislikes.add(request.user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('image_details', args=[slug]))
```

As you can see, my code is basically duplicated and they both work well individually, what I'm trying to do is combine them into one function where if I have already 'liked' my page, I can click the 'dislike' button to dislike my page and remove my 'like'

Many thanks in advance!

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
content = models.TextField()
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts")
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='image_likes', blank=True)
dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='image_dislikes', blank=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ["-created_on"]

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def number_of_likes(self):
    return self.likes.count()

def number_of_dislikes(self):
    return self.dislikes.count()
```

image_details.html (where it is rendered):

```
        <form action="{% url 'post_like' post.slug %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if liked %}
        <span class="text-secondary like-buttons"><strong>{{ post.number_of_likes }} = </strong>
            <button type="submit" name="post_id" class="btn like-buttons" value="{{post.slug}}">
                <ion-icon name="heart-outline"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </span>
        <span class="text-secondary like-buttons"><strong>{{ post.number_of_dislikes }} = </strong>
            <button type="submit" name="post_id" class="btn like-buttons" value="{{post.slug}}">
                <ion-icon name="heart-dislike-outline"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </span>
        {% else %}
        <span class="text-secondary like-buttons"><strong>{{ post.number_of_likes }} = </strong>
            <button type="submit" name="post_id" class="btn like-buttons" value="{{post.slug}}">
                <ion-icon name="heart-outline"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </span>

        <span class="text-secondary like-buttons"><strong>{{ post.number_of_dislikes }} = </strong>
            <button type="submit" name="post_id" class="btn like-buttons" value="{{post.slug}}">
                <ion-icon name="heart-dislike-outline"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </span>
        
    </form>
```

Again, thanks for the answers so far!

Comment: Are the states simply liked/disliked? Or are they liked/neutral/disliked? Your code, which adds or removes, seems to suggest the latter.

Comment: @dougiemath You can save the attribute `post.likes` and `post.dislikes` as variables, then call the methods from the variable e.g `action=post.likes or post.dislikes #depending on your criteria; if action.filter (...): action.remove(); else : ...`

Comment: Please share your model. I would advise *not* to work with two m2m fields, since that makes it hard to ensure that a user does not end up in both m2m relations, and also makes annotating more problematic since it will join on both relations.

Comment: @jarmod thanks for your comment, I hadn't really thought of it but having a neutral state would make sense as both buttons could remain inactive.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for having a look, I've updated the main post, hope this is enough

Comment: @Mugoma I will give this a try and let you know - I'm still a newb at this but I'm very eager to learn more.  I'll keep you posted :)